# Why did Rabindranath Tagore marry such a young girl?

Tags: indian

[Rabindranath Tagore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabindranath_Tagore)'s family was a part of the *Brahmo Somaj* and even his marriage with Bhabatarini Roy later named Mrinalini Devi, was completed following the rules of *Brahmo Somaj*. But my question is that when Mrinalini was married to Tagore, she was just 9. Is this not an implication of child marriage? Being a *Brahmo*, and someone who supported women empowerment, why did Tagore marry such a young girl and, even if he did educate her, she gave birth to the first child within 3 years of marriage, when she was just 12.

Comment: Is Brahmo Somaj the same as [Brahmo Samaj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmo_Samaj)?

Comment: You may find some more details [here.](https://books.google.com/books?id=v08xxlHuWtUC&pg=PA57&dq=Tagore+mrinalini+young+marriage&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&ovdme=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM67Cs3oGAAxUgKlkFHV-qAyMQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: I think sharp distinction into child/adult (like child marriage, child labor, etc.) is a rather recent phenomenon - dating perhaps from XIX-th century. Before that they didn't see childhood as a particularly distinct phase of life.